# Cant get past Ubuntu emergency mode w/ Windows 7 dual boot after running Boot-repair

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-7, dell

I am new to Ubuntu and I apologize if the answer to my problem is easy, but I assure you all that I have search thoroughly for the answer and could not find it.

For the past 5 days I have been trying to set up a Dell t3500 dual boot Ubuntu/Win7 rig. My current issue is every time I boot from grub, Ubuntu goes straight into emergency mode, this happened after running “boot-repair”. Windows 7 runs just fine.

I originally ran boot-repair because I could not get into Ubuntu, after installing windows because it would just go straight into Win7 without giving me the option of choosing Ubuntu. I had the same issue not being able to get into windows but I booted a flashUSB and auto-updated from there. That seemed to fix the boot menu issues. The code below is from the journalctl -xb (All RED errors).

My OS's are both on the same HD, and I used Gparted to partition them. Again, apologies if I am not including enough information or if this has been answered before but I'm having a really hard time.

```
  Jun 04 20:53:18 ubuntu kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
Jun 04 20:53:18 ubuntu kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 04 20:53:19 ubuntu kernel: dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
Jun 04 20:53:31 ubuntu pulseaudio[2051]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Jun 04 20:53:56 ubuntu pulseaudio[1961]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: t
Jun 04 20:54:00 ubuntu ubiquity[1851]: log-output -t ubiquity debconf-copydb configdb targetdb -p ^oem-config/ --config=Name:targetdb --config=Driver:File --config=Mode:0644 --config=F
Jun 04 20:54:00 ubuntu ubiquity[1851]: log-output -t ubiquity debconf-copydb configdb targetdb -p ^keyboard-configuration/ --config=Name:targetdb --config=Driver:File --config=Mode:064
Jun 04 20:54:01 ubuntu ubiquity[1851]: log-output -t ubiquity debconf-copydb configdb targetdb -p ^console-setup/ --config=Name:targetdb --config=Driver:File --config=Mode:0644 --confi
Jun 04 20:54:06 ubuntu spice-vdagent[6053]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Jun 04 20:54:12 ubuntu colord-sane[6149]: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
```

/home/ubuntu/Downloads/IMG_2486.JPG

[image]

[image]

Comment: With nVidia, you need nomodeset until you install the proprietary nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.
How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2 - both BIOS liveCD & grub first boot ( also UEFI with grub) 
How to add boot parameters,  grub menu after install (also grub when UEFI)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132